# whereIn array to string convertion error - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

I am wanting to use the `WhereIn` function on my Eloquent query, and it requires a PHP array:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```

Currently, the data is being passed into the controller in this format -

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(1) "6" }
```

I am wanting the above data to be casted to `(1,4,6)` format to utilise the function but I'm unsure how.

This is currently being used in the following code (bedrooms and property_type are shown in the above format):

```
$bedrooms = Input::get('bedrooms');
$property_type = Input::get('property_type');

$locations = Location::whereHas('coordinate', function ($q) use ($minlat, $maxlat,
             $minlng, $maxlng, $bedrooms, $property_type)
            {
                $q->whereBetween('lat', array($minlat, $maxlat))
                ->whereBetween('lng', array($minlng, $maxlng))
                ->whereIn('bedrooms', '=', $bedrooms)
                ->whereIn('type', '=', $property_type);

            })->lists('id');
```

This returns a `Array to string conversion` error.

My Laravel version is 4.2.* - dev.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: If my solution below does not work please post your entire controller.

Comment: I don't believe whereIn takes 3 parameters. You are trying to cast '=' to an array in your whereIn statements remove this and it should work or at least get ride of the Array to string error. Let me know an i'll update my answer below.

Comment: Exactly the above! Thank you @mschuett! You have an eye for detail. Removing the third parameter solved this problem and returned the anticipated results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to do this. Have you tried it without casting them to ints? If you are not able to do this post what version of laravel you are using so people who come across this later don't do needless work. In laravel 4.2.* the following code will return the proper rows. I have just tested this.

```
Route::get('/', function(){

    $t = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', array('1','2','3'))->get();

    dd($t);

});
```

This also works.

```
Route::get('/', function(){

    $t = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', array(1,2,3))->get();

    dd($t);

});
```

Furthermore this code you have

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "4" [2]=> string(1) "6" }
```

And this code are exactly the same. One has just being displayed using var_dump.

```
array("1", "4", "6")
```

Unless you are literally storing unserialized arrays in your database in which case you have a ton of other issues.

EDIT: After controller was posted

I don't believe whereIn takes 3 parameters. You are trying to cast '=' to an array in your whereIn statements remove this and it should work or at least get ride of the Array to string error.

[Link to whereIn Laravel function.](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/88470f6548a1cc5d148a8eb660e2ac7e753e9431/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php#L305)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Controller and improved explanation posted above @mschuett.

Answer (score 2):

First: I think Laravel can handle string typed items to be put in a sql where clause where the column is an integers.

Second: if it doesn't work you can always 'cast' those strings to integers with the `array_map` method.

More information here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

In your example:

```
$ids = array('1', '4', '6');

$ids = array_map(function ($value) {
    return (int) $value;
}, $ids);

$users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

Hope this helps.